# Style elements dynamically

Tags: php, css, html

I create boxes with text, images, buttons etc. dynamically with a CMS. I don't want to use inline styles but I want the user to define e.g. a text color or a button size. My first attempt was to just give the elements a unique class with PHP and put style tags in the elements like:

```
<?php $element_class = uniqid(); ?>

<article class="element-<?php echo $element_class; ?>">
<style type="text/css">
    element-<?php echo $element_class; ?> {
       color: <?php echo $dynamic_color; ?>;
    }
</style>
<p>Some text</p>
</article>
```

So every Element has it's own style defined - works, but it's ugly and not HTML standard to put style tags outside the head of a page.

Any idea how to style the elements dynamically in a HTML5 compatible way?

Comment: Could you create/maintain a user-generated css file, when they define the styles? Then include the single/multiple css files.

Comment: `<style>` *is* allowed outside of `<head>`, if you add the `scoped` attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=scoped. I think "scoped" was kicked.

Comment: Hm ... as the page is dynamic - how do I give the elements a unique ID and get the same IDs in the header? In your example the two elements are not dynamic.